# Laravel fortify login with remember not work

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, fortify, laravel-fortify

Sorry that my English is weak,

I use fortify with custom login with single page application (vue js), how can add remember me to my custom login

**Note: The browser does not logout when closed. It stays until you are finished expiration session**

```
Fortify::authenticateUsing(function (Request $request) {
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
                    'email' => 'required|email',
                ]);
                $validatorname = Validator::make($request->all(), [
                    'username' => 'required',
                ]);
                $email = $request->email;
                if ($validator->fails()) {
                    if ($validatorname->fails()) {
                        return response()->json($validator->errors(), 422);
                    } else {
                        $user = User::where('user_name', '=', $email)->first();
                    }
                } else {
                    $user = User::where('email', '=', $email)->first();
                }
                if (
                    $user &&
                    Hash::check($request->password, $user->password)
                ) {
                    if ($user->user_status == 2) {          
                        return  $user;
                    }
                    } else if ($user->user_status == 1) {
                        throw ValidationException::withMessages([
                            Fortify::username() => "Your Account is not verify yet",
                        ]);
                    }
                }
   });
```

Comment: Is `remember` part of your request? After using your custom `authenticateUsing(...)` Laravel will login the user using `remember` from the request: https://github.com/laravel/fortify/issues/17#issuecomment-710078430